# Javascript: Convert JSON Array to Cascaded JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have this simple JSON array structure

```
[
  [ "1000", "Kangar","Perlis" ],
  [ "1532", "Kangar", "Perlis" ],
  [ "2000", "Kuala Perlis", "Perlis" ],
  [ "6250", "Alor Setar", "Kedah" ],
  [ "6300", "Kuala Nerang", "Kedah" ]
]
```

Now i want to structure the JSON like this

```
{
    "Perlis": 
    { 
         "Kangar": [ "1000", "1532" ],
         "Kuala Perlis": [ "2000" ]                
     },
    "Kedah":  
    {
        "Alor Setar":["6250"],
        "Kuala Nerang":["2000"]
    }
}
```

So how can i achieve this result using Javascript's object?

Comment: You can use [the space argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_space_argument) of `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```js
var arr = [
  ["1000", "Kangar", "Perlis"],
  ["1532", "Kangar", "Perlis"],
  ["2000", "Kuala Perlis", "Perlis"],
  ["6250", "Alor Setar", "Kedah"],
  ["6300", "Kuala Nerang", "Kedah"]
];

var obj = {};

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  obj[item[2]] = obj[item[2]] || {};
  obj[item[2]][item[1]] = obj[item[2]][item[1]] || [];
  obj[item[2]][item[1]].push(item[0]);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Compact version -

collection.forEach(function(row){
 ((obj[row[2]] || (obj[row[2]] = {}))[row[1]] || (obj[row[2]][row[1]] = [])).push(row[0]);
});

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to create the hash object like this:

```js
function transform(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(hash, sub) {
    if(hash [sub[2]]) {                       // if we hashed the first-level-categry (sub[2])
      if(hash [sub[2]] [sub[1]])              // -- if we hashed the second-level category (sub[1])
        hash [sub[2]] [sub[1]].push(sub[0]);  // ---- add the item (sub[0]) to that array
      else                                    // -- otherwise
        hash [sub[2]] [sub[1]] = [sub[0]];    // ---- create second-level-category placeholder (new array) that initially contains the current item (sub[0])
    }
    else {                                    // else
      hash [sub[2]] = {};                     // -- create the first-level-category placeholder
      hash [sub[2]] [sub[1]] = [sub[0]];      // -- create the second-level-category placeholder (new array) that initially contains the current item (sub[0])
    }
    return hash;
  }, {});
}


var array = [
  ["1000","Kangar","Perlis"],
  ["1532","Kangar","Perlis"],
  ["2000","Kuala Perlis","Perlis"],
  ["6250","Alor Setar","Kedah"],
  ["6300","Kuala Nerang","Kedah"]
];

console.log(transform(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inputArr = [
  ["1000","Kangar","Perlis"],
  ["1532","Kangar","Perlis"],
  ["2000","Kuala Perlis","Perlis"],
  ["6250","Alor Setar","Kedah"],
  ["6300","Kuala Nerang","Kedah"]
];
var processFunction = function(arr){

var outputObj = {};
arr.forEach( function(elem){
  if( !outputObj[ elem[2] ] )
    outputObj[ elem[2] ] ={};
  if( !outputObj[ elem[2] ] [ elem[1] ])
    outputObj[ elem[2] ][ elem[1] ] = [];
  outputObj[ elem[2] ][ elem[1] ].push( elem[0] );
  
});
return outputObj;
};

alert(JSON.stringify(processFunction(inputArr)) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [
  ["1000", "Kangar", "Perlis"],
  ["1532", "Kangar", "Perlis"],
  ["2000", "Kuala Perlis", "Perlis"],
  ["6250", "Alor Setar", "Kedah"],
  ["6300", "Kuala Nerang", "Kedah"]
]

function convert(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (o, e) {
    o[e[2]] = o[e[2]] || {};
    o[e[2]][e[1]] = o[e[2]][e[1]] || [];
    o[e[2]][e[1]].push(e[0]);
    return o;
  }, {});
}

console.log(convert(arr));
```

What this `o[e[2]] = o[e[2]] || {}` does is it sets `o[e[2]]` to itself, or if it's a falsy value (like `undefined`) - to a new object. This acts as an easy initialization and prevents accessing non-existent values.

To be safe, you can add a check for each array element's length:

```
return arr.reduce(function(o, e) {
  if (e.length === 3) {
    ...
  }

  return o;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `reduce()`.

```js
var data = [
  ["1000", "Kangar", "Perlis"],
  ["1532", "Kangar", "Perlis"],
  ["2000", "Kuala Perlis", "Perlis"],
  ["6250", "Alor Setar", "Kedah"],
  ["6300", "Kuala Nerang", "Kedah"]
]

var o = {}
var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!o[e[1]]) {
    o[e[1]] = {[e[1]]: []}
    r[e[2]] = Object.assign((r[e[2]] || {}), o[e[1]])
  }
  o[e[1]][e[1]].push(e[0])
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```